# Install public key via ssh-copy-id for other users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

`ssh-copy-id` can be used to install your public key in a remote machine's `authorized_keys`. Could the same command be used to install other users' public keys, if you have `sudo` ability?

Update: both local and remote are using Ubuntu 12.04.

Update 2: describing the procedure of creating a new user account and adding public key

1. (remote) Create a new user account, and set it to user public key access only.
2. (local) Generate a public key for the new user account (ssh-keygen).
3. Normally I do is to create the directory and file `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote server, then copy and paste the public key generated locally to the new user's account. What I am looking for is that if I can use `ssh-copy-id` to install this newly created user's public key directly into the ssh directory. Just to save a couple more commands.

Comment: 7 years. any updates on how to do this in one line?

Comment: Save yourselves the hassle and use the webmin plugin to do it with a gui

Answer (score 23):

Not the same command but if you can use sudo on the remote host, you can use ssh to remotely do the required steps. I use the following command to push my ssh key to my raspberry's root user:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | \
  ssh pi@192.168.1.25 \
  "sudo mkdir -p /root/.ssh; sudo tee -a /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

- cats my public key
- pipes it to ssh
- ssh connects to my raspberry as ssh user
- on remote uses sudo to create /root/.ssh
- then uses sudo with "tee -a" to append stdin (which holds the key from first cat) to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Just put this stuff together as a script, maybe add some chmod/chown on the remote side and you have what you need.

Comment: Beautiful and thank you for the command breakdown.

Comment: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh pi@192.168.1.25 "sudo cat >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"` is for you if .ssh exists.

Comment: Don't you have to set permissions as well of the dir & key?

Comment: @Timo `sudo cat >>` is unlikely to work. It would run cat as root which reads from pipe and writes to pipe. the pipe is read by the shell spawned by ssh which runs as "pi" user and has no write permission to the target folder. That's why tee is used here and in most similar examples.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

- the `root` user can already login via ssh (password or ssh-key)
- the user `svruser` already exists on the server and has passwordless sudo rights
- I want to allow the `svruser` to login via ssh-key: i.e. upload the public ssh key, that is stored on my local PC to the remote server and append it to the `authorized_keys` file

This command worked for me:

```bash
cat LOCAL/PATH/my-ssh.pub | ssh root@my.host.com \
"sudo -u svruser bash -c 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh; chmod 700 ~/.ssh; tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'"
```

Details

- execute this on my local PC in a terminal where ssh is installed (e.g. Linux terminal, WSL, or git-bash on windows)
- `cat LOCAL/PATH/my-ssh.pub` just prints the file contents of my public ssh key to the terminal
- `|` pipes the text of the ssh-key to the next (ssh) command
- `ssh root@my.host.com`: connect via ssh as user `root` to my host

  - `sudo -u svruser`: execute the following command as user `svruser`

    - `bash -c '..'` executes the text inside of the single quotes in a bash hell

      - `mkdir -p ~/.ssh` create the (hidden) `.ssh` dir in the home-directory of the `svruser`
      - `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`: set the right permissions to the new dir: see [Permissions on private key in .ssh folder?](https://superuser.com/a/215506/257979)
      - `tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`: prints the ssh-key text (that we piped to the ssh command) to the terminal and appends the text to the `authorized_keys` file

Answer (score 0):

Provided that we have access to the server at ADDRESS with the `root` user and the user we want to set up keys for is called `ubuntu`, the following one-liner can be used.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@ADDRESS "su - ubuntu -c 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh && tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'"
```

This will work regardless whether `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` exist or not.

Comment: Don't you have to set permissions as well of the dir & key?

Comment: I checked it. It works like this, because you are running `mkdir` and `tee` as the `ubuntu` user to whom the keys should be assigned. So `ubuntu` will be the owner of `.ssh` and `authorized_keys`.