# Finding sshd log file

Tags: ssh, sshd, password-protection, public-key-encryption, private-key

I'm experiencing some problems with SSHD on my server.
I'm trying to set up passwordless (pub/pv keys) authentication. It worked for my other servers, but not for this one. The SSHD agent adds my public key in "authorized keys" but still asks for password.
I tried to disable totally password authentication (in /etc/ssh/sshd_conf) to see what happens, and I get "bad pub key".

The pub key is sent by the client (ssh -vvv) :

```
 ----
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
 debug3: send_pubkey_test
 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
 debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
 ----
 ## Next key (rsa was the good one)
```

I checked "sshd_config" and ".ssh" permissions
Now I just want to be able to see what happens on the server side.
I checked my "/var/log/auth" and "/var/log/secure", but no file here.

In the config, I configured logs as follows :

```
 SyslogFacility AUTH
 LogLevel DEBUG
```

How can I debug my situation without using deep network sniffing ? Is it possible to redirect Sshd output to a logfile or std ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The way to see what is going on on the server is to start the sshd daemon with these options:

```
  /usr/sbin/sshd -dD
```

The two options are (from the Man page):

> -D      When this option is specified, sshd will not detach and does not become a daemon.  This allows easy
>                monitoring of sshd.
>
> ```
> -d      Debug mode.  The server sends verbose debug output to standard error, and does not put itself in the
>          background.  The server also will not fork and will only process one connection.  This option is only
>          intended for debugging for the server.  Multiple -d options increase the debugging level.  Maximum is
>          3.
> ```

This should be plenty. For the past, it depends on your distro. I get messages in /var/log/auth.log, but you can search for messages relating to ssh in the same directory by means of

```
    find /var/log -type f -exec grep -l ssh {} \;
```

which will output the names of all files containing the expression `ssh`. You will then have to check their content.

Answer (score 0):

You write How can I debug my situation without using deep network sniffing ? Is it possible to redirect Sshd output to a logfile or std ?"

Well, you could include in your troubleshooting and question, noting down how you created the key, and how you put the key into authorized_keys on the remote side. And the permissions [Permissions on private key in .ssh folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder)

My answer to this question

[When I try to log in with SSH, why am I getting the error, Permission denied (publickey)](https://superuser.com/questions/1355768/when-i-try-to-log-in-with-ssh-why-am-i-getting-the-error-permission-denied-pu)

includes an example of redirecting the -v output to a file `$ ssh -v user@ip pwd 2>a.a` along with some things to look for to catch a public key issue or an incorrect user issue.