# can not access my ubuntu server through putty

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty, amazon-web-services, remote-access

I was able to access my ubuntu server through putty. but suddenly it stops working. Server is working fine . I can access through aws console

but when I try to access through putty I receive this error.

I don't know why server refusing key it is same what i was using before

this is error `no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey) aws`

I created new instance and same thing happend after one day. is it happening because of 777 access to files ? in my project i give 777 access to files after every 1 hours

Stack exchange didn't allow me to post images

Comment: SSH needs specific permissions. Have a look at this answer to see if it helps. If it doesn't help report back a bit more info https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's how it goes.

> The `.ssh` directory needs to have **755** permissions and be owned by
> the user. The `authorized_keys` file needs to have **644** permissions
> and be owned by the user.

If you give 777 access to everything, it very well could be the issue. Any specific reason why you want 777 for everything?

Comment: i am giving these permissions to my project file not .ssh

Comment: Can you please check whether your `.ssh` permissions are ok?

Comment: can you please tell me command how I can check permissions for .ssh

Comment: A simple list command world work. `ll`